# Azure DevOps Pipelines - "nodejs: command not found" when running bash script

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to run a Bash script in an Azure DevOps Pipeline, see below my yaml file:

```
trigger:
  - master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0 
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '12.x'
    displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'filePath'
    filePath: 'build.sh'
```

The pipeline is calling a "build.sh" script that calls node.js, and that is why I install the tool before running the script. However, I get the following message:

> /home/vsts/work/1/s/build.sh: line 5: nodejs: command not found

This is the line 5 in the "build.sh" script, and it is working when I run it directly from my computer:

```
nodejs ../bin/r.js -o baseUrl=. optimize=none name=main out=main-built.js exclude=jquery.js
```

I have tried different approaches but cannot make it work. Any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use `node` instead if `nodejs`

```yaml
steps:
- task: NodeTool@0 
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '12.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'node --version'
- task: Bash@3
  continueOnError: true
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'nodejs --version'
```

then I got for `node --version`

> v12.19.0

and for `nodejs --version`

> /home/vsts/work/_temp/6287b2ad-1b03-48fd-a4df-3cf7ad6c9971.sh: line 1: nodejs: command not found